# How do I reload a config module when the contents change in Node.js?

Tags: javascript, node.js, configuration, config

I have several js that read in several variables from a config.js file which in turn had already read local environment variables.

I want to be able to allow a user to update these values (via an HTTP POST). How do I make these changes take effect. Changing the config.js values or the environment values doesn't take effect because the files that leverage the config file have already loaded the variables.

Answer (score 0):

You could declare the variables using `getters` and `setters` so that you can have a function implementation behind the variable.

Here's an example:

```
'use strict';

let value = null;

module.exports = Object.create(Object.prototype, {
    value: {
        get: () => {
            return value;
        },
        set: (val) => {
            value = val;
        }
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You could put them in a module, say `app-config.js`, that exposes get/set so you can set them from your api method.  If they are just internal variables inside of a module somewhere then there is no way to change them.

You didn't say if you're using ES5 or ES6, if you need an example of how to do this please specify and I can add one.

Here are some links that may help you

http://www.benmvp.com/learning-es6-enhanced-object-literals/ (Method Definition Shorthand section)

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/defineProperty